# Triples of [a,b,c] satisfying a +b + c < d

Tags: algorithm

> Given an array A containing a million integer values and a given value d, find all the triples such that `a + b + c <= d` For example, let `A = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}` and `d = 7`, Possible triples are `[1,2,3] [1,2,4]`
>
> Also assume that a number of the array cannot be used more than once in a triple. So `[1,1,1]` cannot be a valid triple.

Second part of question says to find quadruples [a,b,c,d] such that `a +b + c <= d` is still valid. Here d is not given and is an array element just like a,b and c

Above question seems to have been asked in a Google Interview

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an interview question that contains no attempts to solve the question itself from the op.

Comment: Are all numbers positive?

Comment: Are all array number positive and unique?

Comment: @DavidThomas, "apartment interview" ??

Comment: @DavidThomas:  Merely not having any attempts at a solution doesn't make a bad question in and of itself.  It could easily be the case that the math behind the problem isn't understood, so one would be at a gross disadvantage starting out writing code.

Comment: Perhaps, but how is this not a "give me teh codez" question? And while I am voting to close, my vote should in no way influence your own choices, although I, obviously, feel I'm correct. (Also: autocorrect, dammit...)

Comment: Assuming that A only contains positive numbers, this doesn't seem that difficult to solve if starting with the 3 smallest values of A as the triplet.

Comment: Personally I think it's a math question as opposed to a programming question altogether.  The math isn't understood so a programming solution would be worthless in this context.  So, Nomad, that means you would need to look into the [subset sum](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SubsetSumProblem.html) problem.  Once you get some research under your belt there, ask specific questions about the algorithm over on Math.SE (or find an existing answer there).  When you're ready to try to implement a solution for yourself, we'll be happy to help you with any potential coding problems.

Comment: @DavidThomas, it's just an basic algorithm question. Do all such question need to show prior effort?

Comment: Is my answer to that not implicit in my previous comments? If you feel my vote is problematic then please do consider raising the issue on [meta], comments are (intended) to request clarification of the question itself, not to foster a discussion amongst commenters.

Comment: Guys, after reading all the comments here I am kinda scared to post questions to SO. This is my first question posted on SO. First i posted it on Code Golf and they redirected me here. All I am looking for is some approaches to solve the problem.

Comment: This is the algorithm I came up for the 1st part of the question. For each value of a we need to pairs b and c such that b +c <= (d- a). For this problem we can balanced binary search trees with augmented data structure to get the pairs b and c that satisfy the condition. However this will only give me the count of such pairs and not the actual pairs. So the algorithm to count such pairs would be O(n^2logn). Also please be gentle. Don't scare me away :P

Comment: Would it be cheating to use list comprehensions as provided by Haskell? Or am I missing the point that a push in the right direction is needed, not so much the implementation?

Comment: @DavidThomas I agree that it is an interview question, but it is also a programming question. Also I have demonstrated my idea of solving the problem in a comment. I don't see any valid reason to believe that is off topic

Answer (score 2):

Sort the array and get your value of d
for all 
Tracking each element one by one .. Setting value of 'a' between first elem and third last element.
Then apply same thing for doublets (find all doublets (b,c) whose sum is <= (d-a)) between the first element and the 'd'

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
for i in 2..n-1
  for j in 1..i-1
     for k in 0..j-1
        if A[i]+A[j]+A[k] <= d
          print A[i], A[j], A[k]
```

Here n is the number of integers in A. If the integers in A are not unique, a unique list has to be created first. There is a lot of room for optimisation if A is first sorted.

Comment: This works, but it would be better to sort the array first and then terminate loops when sum > d.

Comment: Exactly. Hence the last sentence :) This was just a very simple implementation. And depending on the language the actual code may be very short. In python it is a short one-liner [(a,b,c) for a in range(n) for b in range(a) for c in range(b) if a+b+c <= d].

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to search all elements in about O(N^2). For this you'll need an array if your elements are smaller then one million, where appear[i] = 1, only if i appears in A. If the elements are bigger then one million you can use a hash table. Now you can iterate in your array with an a and b. Because you have d, you'll know how much is d-a, you know b so c will be d-a-b if appear[d-a-b] = 1, or the closest smaller element to this which have appear[element] = 1.
For hash table the idea is the same, you'll just have to change the search of c.